# Au-haue as regional to Hamburg?

Tags: dialect, slang, low-german

Back in the day when I was in Hamburg (ca. early 1980s), my girlfriend would say something like *au-haue* which meant "oh, wow" or "oh my." Was I imagining that? I've never heard or seen it since. Otherwise, Hamburgers seem to speak very understandable Hochdeutsch.

Comment: Could it have been [auweia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/auweia#:~:text=(file)-,Interjection,!%2C%20oops!%2C%20shoot!)

Comment: No, distinctly auhaue. As in au hauen.

Comment: I thought of the Werner comic book "Ouhauerha!", but that was only published in 1992. Werner himself has been around since 1978. But it could very well be that "Ouhauerha" (or something similar) was in use in northern Germany for quite some time before making it into the written language.

Comment: Werner Flaschbier? That might have been it. She was a WF fan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it in a slightly different spelling ***Au haua ha*** or also as an enhancement in the form ***au haua haua ha*** and I think it stands colloquially for *what a bummer - oh my goodness*.

Regionally, I place the slang in northern Germany with the coast of the North Sea and the Baltic Sea (sailors?). Unfortunately, I haven't found a source.

[For fun see and hear also the video clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R7SqgvyNuT4#t=00m08s)

Comment: The spelling I know is "Ohaueha", like here: https://www.verlagsgruppe.de/produktdetails/product/delfs-renate-ohaueha-wasn-aggewars.html